# Unable to resolve module `schedule/tracking`

Tags: ios, react-native

So I made a react-native project that fully works on android now, but when I try to run it on ios I keep getting more problems.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wf9I.jpg)

I know this question is already all over stackoverflow and the react-native github page, but all those answers don't seem to work for me and I doubt anyone checks those comments anymore.

I had a similar problem on another project but IIRC that was solved by updating my RN version.
Does anyone know what I did wrong here?

I already tried:

- updating RN
- downgrading RN
- installing @babel/runtime: 7.0.0
- installing schedule: 0.4.0
- removing all the '^'-characters of the package version
- remove node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling
- ...

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0",
  "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
  "react-native": "0.57.2",
  "react-native-fetch-blob": "0.10.8",
  "react-native-orientation": "3.1.3",
  "react-navigation": "3.0.9"
},
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
  "jest": "23.6.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
  "schedule": "0.4.0"
},
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that I am also experiencing this, and none of the solutions you tried helped me either.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I forgot to remove all of node_modules after installing that version of schedule. Got another error because I updated navigation, but now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Few things that may guide you in the right direction.

1. Are you sure you want the dependency on the `devDependencies` section, instead of `dependencies`? Development dependencies are for the tooling used for your project, not the project itself. Importing code from `devDependencies` directly in your application code is a code smell. Also, which may be a case for you, some CI servers may not install `devDependencies` by default.
2. There is no `tracking` file in the 0.4 version of the package. However, there is a `tracing.js` file. Are you sure you're importing the right file? You can browse all files bundled in the package [here](https://unpkg.com/schedule@0.4.0/).
3. As the documentation states: "This is a package for cooperative scheduling in a **browser** environment.". Are you're sure you can use it in React Native?

Last two points don't explain why it works on Android and not on iOS thou.

If you don't need `schedule` package directly, and you install it only because of the error, then you should remove it from `package.json` as it shouldn't be there in the first place (remember to remove `node_modules` / clean cache afterward).
This is an internal React package, and you should not use it directly unless you knew what you are doing. In this case, the root cause of the initial error is probably something different.